# Is there GLSL problem with float uniform rounding

Tags: shader, glsles

I pass Unix time to my shader from Java code:
`gl.uniform1f(shader, System.currentTimeMillis());`

The shader looks like (simple form, just to investigate the problem):

```
#ifdef GLES
precision highp float;
#endif

uniform float u_time;

void main() {
  int d = 1000;
  float result = floor(u_time / d) * d;
  if (result > u_time) {
    s = 1.0;
  } else {
    s = 0.5;
  }
  gl_FragColor = vec4(s, 0, 0, 1.0);
}
```

I expect that `result` will never be greater than `u_time`. Surprisingly it IS (shader produces bright red color).

Moreover, if replace value of `d` with 100, for example, it works as expected - renders dark red.

Tried to replace `d` with `float` value of 100.0, but without any effect.

It works even if I replace `u_time` in expression with direct float constant, for example 1563854457241.0 - it is about the same, that Java puts to shader.

What may be the problem? I suspect it relates to precision, but do not undertand how to fix it.

P.S. After all, I got TRUE (bright red color) if replace condition expression with

**1000000123.0 * 1000 == 1000000123456.0**

Nuf said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your shader code you've exceeded the precision limit of a 32 bit floating point number.
See [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) and [GLSL ES -Precision and Precision Qualifiers](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/es/3.2/GLSL_ES_Specification_3.20.html#precision-and-precision-qualifiers).
When you use the precision qualifier `highp`, then the number of significant bit is 23 (+1 for the sign), so a number like `1000000123456.0` can not be represented with the full precision, because the approximated number of decimal digits is 7.22.